# Отсортировать список по условию

Tags: c#, list

У меня есть список работников, которые хранятся в файле `json` в таком виде:

`"FullName":"Иванов Иван Иванович","Departaments":"Цех 1","Salary":25000,"PersonIsLeader":null`

Я их считал в `List<Employee>` и мне нужно сделать выборку из этого списка так, чтобы в новый список записались только те люди, которые работают в `Цех 1`.

Вот сам класс:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Departaments { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
        public bool PersonIsLeader { get; set;  }
    }
```

`var filtredEmployees = DataReader.readedFile.OrderBy(x => x.FullName).ThenBy(x => x.Departaments == "Цех 1").ToList();`

Я пытаюсь сделать это так, но не работает. Поэтому прошу помощи.

Answer (score 1):

Cделал выборку вот так:
`var filtredEmployees = DataReader.readedFile.Where(x => x.Departaments == "Цех 1" && x.PersonIsLeader).ToList();`

Comment: Не `Select`, а `Where` наверное?

Comment: @aepot Да, спасибо, `where` еще лучше, даже выборку по `false` и `true` не нужно делать

Comment: `x.PersonIsLeader == true` тут `== true` излишне, достаточно просто `x.PersonIsLeader`.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, точно, исправил, спасибо большое

Comment: @CrazyElf Только так вроде не компилируется, потому что у меня не просто `bool` а `bool?`

Comment: `x.PersonIsLeader ?? false` можно еще :) Но вообще не понятно, зачем вам там null.

Comment: @aepot Да, мне подсказали, что можно просто `bool` использовать, я думал задание подразумевает `nullable`, но можно и без него

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin А, сорри, не видел, что там был `bool?` )  Ну оказалось, что и не нужен был, и хорошо.